# Excel #Value error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to count occurrence of a range in workbook1 in all the sheets in workbook2.
I used `countif`, but if workbook2 is not opened, `countif` throws a #value error in workbook1.
I also tried with `sumproduct`. But since I have thousands of rows, it takes a long time to calculate the sheet.
I guess index would also take lot of time to calculate.
Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: SO is a site that helps in solving programming problems. Typically this includes a [mcve] which helps to replicate and understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIF & SUMIF cannot reference a closed workbook.  I can think of 2 options:

1. Create a "data collection" tab (which you can keep hidden) in wrkbk1 that performs the countif calculation.  Then link wrkbk2 to the "data collection" tab in wrkbk1.  This should resolve the reference error.
2. Keep it as is and use an array formula in wrkbk2 :

   {countif(if('path[filename]tabname'!$A:$A="whateveryouarelookingfor",1))}

Make sure you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering the above formula to activate it as a formula.